# Ionic 2 login with facebook in ios getting error

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working with the iconic development and in my app, requirement is to make login with facebook but i Can't Load URL The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings. In ionic 2 for platform ios getting this error i try with my domins add in facebbok app but still getting error please any one have idea or solution for that then suggest me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i remove my old code and app from facebook account and created new app and added platforms and installed facebook 4 plugin in ionic 2 then everything is working fine for me.:)